# Google sheets Paste Format

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste, google-sheets-macros

In the below Google Sheets code I am copying two months of calendar data from separate monthly sheets and pasting it into the "TwoMonth" sheet for display purposes.  One function advances the displayed months by one month and the other function does the opposite and backs-up by one month. The idea is to paste the values and the formats in two different statements.  The Forward1Mo function works as expected.  The Reverse1Mo function pastes the values, but fails to paste the format.  The code is virtually identical between the two functions but the performance is not.  What am I doing wrong?

```
function Forward1Mo() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var showMo1 = spreadsheet.getRange('C19').getValue()+1;
    var showMo2 = showMo1+1;

    spreadsheet.getSheetByName(showMo1).getRange('B2:H15').copyTo(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TwoMonth').getRange('B2:H15'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    spreadsheet.getSheetByName(showMo1).getRange('B2:H15').copyTo(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TwoMonth').getRange('B2:H15'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
    spreadsheet.getSheetByName(showMo2).getRange('B2:H15').copyTo(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TwoMonth').getRange('J2:P15'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);  
    spreadsheet.getSheetByName(showMo2).getRange('B2:H15').copyTo(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TwoMonth').getRange('J2:P15'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);  

    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange('C19').setValue(showMo1);
};

function Reverse1Mo() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var showMo1 = spreadsheet.getRange('C19').getValue()-1;
    var showMo2 = showMo1+1;
    spreadsheet.getSheetByName(showMo1).getRange('B2:H15').copyTo(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TwoMonth').getRange('B2:H15'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
    spreadsheet.getSheetByName(showMo1).getRange('B2:H15').copyTo(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TwoMonth').getRange('B2:H15'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);
    spreadsheet.getSheetByName(showMo2).getRange('B2:H15').copyTo(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TwoMonth').getRange('J2:P15'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);  
    spreadsheet.getSheetByName(showMo2).getRange('B2:H15').copyTo(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TwoMonth').getRange('J2:P15'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);  

    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange('C19').setValue(showMo1);
};
```

Comment: Have you tried just `PASTE_NORMAL`? 
[DOC](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/copy-paste-type):     PASTE_NORMAL Paste values, formulas, formats and merges.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Ron.  Yes, I tried PASTE_NORMAL also.  The code seems to work this evening.  Go figure?  I had even closed, saved, and reran the code yesterday to no avail.  Well, I'm new to JS and Google Sheets and surprised how similar this is to Excel and VB!

Answer (score 1):

Today, the code posted above works just fine in Google Sheets.  I had even saved, closed, reopened, and retested the Google Sheet yesterday to no avail.  Today, I opened and tested to find that everything performs as expected.

Hope the code above is of some use to somebody.  The main feature of this code is to present a scroll-able two month view of a workbook made of single month worksheets.  The idea was to present values and formats only to the web facing presentation.  Buttons are provided that invoke either of the two functions shown above.